# Sort text lines by given field

Tags: sorting, awk

I'm trying to sort the following lines of text:

```
bbb = 4
aaaaaaaa = 1a
c = 3aa
ddddd = 2aaaa
```

using as sorting key the value after the '='. What I'd like to obtain is:

```
aaaaaaaa = 1a
ddddd = 2aaaa
c = 3aa
bbb = 4
```

Note that both the first and second fields can have arbitrary length.

As you can see, the sorting should: 1) tokenize each line around the '=' 2) sort the second field (i.e. the number after the '='), 3) print the whole line.

I managed to put together this awk command:

```
cat lines | awk -F "=" '{print $2 | "sort"}'
```

but this will only print the second field and not the whole line.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
cat lines | sort -k 3
```

Comment: Or a little more concisely, `sort -k 3 lines`

Comment: Thanks for the head's up, I didn't know sort had such options. It should actually be:
sort -t '=' -k 2